# run storybook with angular 15 and ionic 7

Tags: angular, npm, ionic-framework, storybook

I installed a new project ionic with angular 15 and ionic 7. I installed storybook like the doc but when I want run storybook I have a problem with @angular/animation.

```
99% end closing watch compilationWARN Force closed preview build
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations' in 'C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\fesm2020'
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1506:33
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:644:18
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:10:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:197:20
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:326:20
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:60:14
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:529:26
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:691:15
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:797:9
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3009:13
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:781:24
    at finishWithoutResolve (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:193:14)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:258:22
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:301:9
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:301:9
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:72:26
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:301:9
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\forEachBail.js:11:16
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\AliasPlugin.js:100:18
    at next (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\forEachBail.js:9:5)
    at forEachBail (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\forEachBail.js:22:10)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\AliasPlugin.js:39:7
    at _next11 (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:8:1)
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:31:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:301:9
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:301:9
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:301:9
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:72:26
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:301:9
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:301:9
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DirectoryExistsPlugin.js:31:20
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)
resolve '@angular/animations' in 'C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\fesm2020'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\package.json (relative path: ./fesm2020)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\fesm2020\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules
        single file module
          using description file: C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/@angular/animations)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\animations doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\animations.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\animations.js doesn't exist
            .jsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\animations.jsx doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\animations.ts doesn't exist
            .tsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\animations.tsx doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\animations.json doesn't exist
            .cjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\animations.cjs doesn't exist
        C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\animations doesn't exist
      C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:/Users/nicolas.lupieri/Desktop/projets/phenix-web
        single file module
          using description file: C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\package.json (relative path: ./@angular/animations)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\@angular\animations doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\@angular\animations.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\@angular\animations.js doesn't exist
            .jsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\@angular\animations.jsx doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\@angular\animations.ts doesn't exist
            .tsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\@angular\animations.tsx doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\@angular\animations.json doesn't exist
            .cjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\@angular\animations.cjs doesn't exist
        C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\@angular\animations doesn't exist
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations/browser' in 'C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\fesm2020'
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1506:33
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:644:18
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:10:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:197:20
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:326:20
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:60:14
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:529:26
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:691:15
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:797:9
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3009:13
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:781:24
    at finishWithoutResolve (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:193:14)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:258:22
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:301:9
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:301:9
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:72:26
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:301:9
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\forEachBail.js:11:16
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\AliasPlugin.js:100:18
    at next (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\forEachBail.js:9:5)
    at forEachBail (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\forEachBail.js:22:10)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\AliasPlugin.js:39:7
    at _next11 (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:8:1)
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:31:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:301:9
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:301:9
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:301:9
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:72:26
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:301:9
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:301:9
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DirectoryExistsPlugin.js:31:20
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)
resolve '@angular/animations/browser' in 'C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\fesm2020'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\package.json (relative path: ./fesm2020)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\fesm2020\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules
        C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\node_modules\@angular\animations doesn't exist
      C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:/Users/nicolas.lupieri/Desktop/projets/phenix-web
        C:\Users\nicolas.lupieri\Desktop\projets\phenix-web\@angular\animations doesn't exist

√ Would you like to help improve Storybook by sending anonymous crash reports? ... yes
Broken build, fix the error above.
You may need to refresh the browser.
```

I tried to install angular/animation but the console return conflicts. And when I force the installation it work but I must force all installation futur and it's not a good solution. I don't understand what is happen. Thx for your help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.